# Maven doesn't initialize the spring context property when running integration tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

**Issue :** When running integration tests from maven (mvn verify) the spring application context is not initialized properly, it doesn't take in consideration my custom ApplicationContextInitializer class.

**Test Class :**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MainApplication.class}, initializers = CustomContextInitializer.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class ApplicationIT {

    // Running a SOAPUI suite as a JUnit Test
    @Test
    public void TestGateway() throws Exception {
        SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
        runner.setProjectFile("../gateway/src/test/resources/soapui/gateway-soapui.xml");
    runner.run();
}
```

}

**MainApplication class :**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    // different packages here (not relevant)
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class)
                .initializers(new CustomContextInitializer())
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

**CustomContextInitiliazer class** (for adding custom **.properties** files to the spring environment application context) :

```
public class CustomContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

        try {
            Resource[] res = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:/*.properties");
            for (Resource re : res) {                
                env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(re));                
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Results :**

1) Everything works on when I start and run the application (either from IDE or by invoking mvn exec).

2) Integration tests run ok when started from IDE.

3) Integration tests throw error when invoked via **maven verify** because the custom properties files are not loaded into spring context environment. The result is the same as if I wouldn't have written **initializers = CustomContextInitializer.class** in the test class and tried to run the tests from IDE.

Comment: Could you share your file structure? I'm interested in where your properties files are located.

Comment: Do you want to test against your production properties files? Or should you create test properties to use during integration testing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, but your `.properties` files may be at the wrong place. Make sure they are under `<project>/src/main/resources` or that you have configured a custom resource folder in maven. If they reside under  `<project>/src/main/java` they will not be part of the classpath as far as maven is concerned.

Comment: Properties files are located in each sub-module in **src/main/resources** . After maven build they are moved in **target/classes/** . Main issue seems to be that the classpath is different when executing with maven verify, it doesn't point to each of the modules anymore but to a temporary created jar : **/C:/ws/project/starter/target/surefire/surefirebooter6807877691996319825.jar** which most likely doesn't contain my .properties files

Comment: Have you declared dependencies between your modules properly?

Comment: Yes, dependencies are ok, the starter module (which contains the integration tests) has dependencies to all other modules.

Comment: Could you try to temporarily copy the properties files to the starter module's src/main/resources and see if it works then? You can also try printing your classpath from within the test to see if you can spot something strange there...

Comment: I'll give it a try. Meanwhile I've managed to find a workaround for loading my properties files from all other modules. Dropped the CustomContextInitializer class and created in each sub-module a "@Configuration" class with "@PropertySources" poiting to that modules properties. The class is empty, used only with the two annotations. This is fine since each module declares only it's own PropertySources files and there are no hardcoded relations between modules.